# How to print own variable without any warning

Tags: bash

I want to set variable and print it without dumb warning "-bash: export: not a valid identifier" and any other. And of course without executing this variables as command. What I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTAINERNAME = box.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)
echo $(CONTAINERNAME)
```

[echo variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1gO8.png)

Comment: Remove spaces around ` = ` on line 2 and remove parentheses around variable name on line 3.

Comment: Since you appear to be unfamiliar with bash shell syntax, you may find [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the third line must be

```
echo $CONTAINERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delete space before and after "=" as below

```
CONTAINERNAME=box.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)
```

Comment: Its don't working ! Error is "./StartContainer.sh: line 3: CONTAINERNAME: command not found"